# How to use Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore extension in a viewer so that I can draw on it?

Tags: autodesk-forge, auto, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

Can you guide me or show some simple example in which I can use extension Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore   in a viewer example, so that i can draw markups on it for adding RFI/Submittal info

Answer (score 0):

You may find the following articles useful:

- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/placing-custom-markup-dbid
- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/create-pushpin-markup-svg
- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/introducing-bim-360-issues-api
- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/using-autodeskviewingmarkupscore-extension

Comment: https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/configurator?id=598d7ec14cabf2c1f4dec948....can I get source code of this?

Comment: git url please?

Comment: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs - Github links also available on the live demo